# pyenv on windows - not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyenv

I have a project were I have t use python 2.7 instead of 3.x. In order to do this, I installed `pyenv-win` on my windows machine but its not working.

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win#finish-the-installation) but still getting in the cmd

`pyenv is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I am wondering is it becaue I put this `%USERPROFILE%` as is without having it as a separate environment variable ? And if this is the case what exactly should this `%USERPROFILE%` be ?

**Update**

- I added `USERPROFILE` as a SYSTEM VARIABLE  I made it the link to my user on the PC i.e. `C:/Users/Anonymous`
- I added `%PYENV%\bin` to user path
- I added `%PYENV%\shims` to user path

Now if I run `pyenv --version` I get `pyenv` **WITHOUT** version specified.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it using cmd `pip install pyenv-win==3.1.1 --target %USERPROFILE%\.pyenv --upgrade` after several failed attempts to manage it via power shell or manually.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this is something normal. After the Update specified above, I ran `pyenv install 2.7` then I ran `pyenv` and I got the following pyenv `1.2.4` Installed